# Option to uncheck all or invert selection in SSDT?

Tags: ssdt, visual-studio-2015

In SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) after compared the schema, I want to update few changes of mine only (as red-circled in the screenshot).

But there are many other changes are listed in the window, I need to manually uncheck all the other items.

Is there any option to uncheck all or invert selection the items?

[image: SSDT]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For those coming here from Google looking for a solution to this (like me), I found the answer [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-swimmer/2017/01/23/how-to-exclude-entire-sections-in-vs-schema-compare/).

> All you have to do is right click on the section and ta-da, you can Include or Exclude all objects depending on the existing state of the objects.

In this case, section means the `Delete`, `Change`, and `Add` parent folders in the schema compare window.

Comment: but unable to check one by 1 table, after exclude

Comment: Still caused Visual Studio to crash =(

Answer (score 1):

With Shift-Leftmousebutton you can select multiple lines.
With Ctrl-Leftmousebutton you can toggle individual lines from the selection.
With Rightmousebutton you can get the popup menu with Include/Exclude options.
[image: Multiple Select/Deselect]